# A name for the sound of liquid discharging from a bottle into a glass

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, sounds

Today, I googled, and could find the terms, like **[dip](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/plop)** and **[plop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dip)**.

Is there any word when we pour water into the glass, and we hear the sound produced within a bottle?

> As I poured myself a drink, I listened to the water ______ into my empty glass.
>
> [image: picture of water pouring into a glass]

Comment: Just FYI, neither "dip" nor "plop" describes that.

Comment: Iqbal, why don't you **REMOVE** the reference to the glass, since you very explicitly DONT WANT the sound of it hitting the glass?

Comment: FWIW all the answers refer to the kind of noise produced when the water comes out alternately with air going in to replace it, which is not what your image depicts. (AFAIK there is no word for the sound of a smooth pour like in the image, probably because it's so quiet you just hear the water landing in the glass.)

Comment: @MissMonicaE, I thought that someone would say the same as you said here. I will change the image, after being online through my PC.

Comment: @MissMonicaE, I did that, see the image now.

Comment: The word *dip* is not onomatopoeic, it describes the action of immersing, or lowering something **in** liquid. You dip (or dunk) a biscuit in a cup of tea, for example. You dip your toes in the sea if you're afraid it is too cold. The water from a receptacle  (bottle, can, basin, etc.) does not dip, it "pours" or "flows".

Comment: I've reworded the sample. If I misinterpreted it, please feel free to roll back the edit or improve on it further. I liked the image but it was way too large before, so now it's much smaller.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try [glug](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/glug).

> **glug** (ɡlʌɡ) *n*
>   a word representing a gurgling sound, as of liquid being poured from a bottle or swallowed

Comment: Isn't it that the **glug** is a sound produced within our throat amid during water.

Comment: Still have doubts. The term **swallowed** in the definition you provided made me think of the sound of throat when drinking water.

Comment: That could also be described as a glugging sound. Onomatopoeia is at work here: the word reflecting the actual sound.

Comment: That is the sound of a liquid passing through a narrow opening, whether it be glass, plastic, ceramic, or flesh. Note that this particular definition says "... being poured from a bottle *or* swallowed." It can go either way, which means it works in either context.

Comment: @Robusto, okay, you mean to say **glug** is a sound for both, from the opening of a bottle and our throat swallowing that water.

Comment: @Zan700, in which sense can we relate the term, **onomatopoeia**, here?

Comment: Onomatopoeia is the formation of words that mimic sounds that occur in the world, such as *buzz* for the sound a bee or fly makes, or *splat* for the sound of a wet item smacking on a hard surface (*smack* itself is probably onomatopoeic as well).

Comment: "Archer **splooshed** several ounces of tequila from the bottle into his tumbler, then drank it in a single motion."

Comment: There was a cartoon with Daffy Duck where at some point he has to pretend he's a champagne bottle, and the waiter 'pours' Daffy, and for Daffy to sound realistically like liquid pouring out of a bottle he says "skoykill, skoykill, skoykill", pronounced like that other river through Philadelphia, the Schuykill.

Comment: Note that glug is a word "representing a gurgling sound".  The word for the gurgling sound is "gurgling"   :)

Comment: +1 This answers fits my usage as a Native American English speaker.  Glug is undoubtedly the sound produced by the bottle as a liquid passes out and air passes in.  Another interesting question would be what word would you use to describe the sound water makes as it lands in the bottom of the glass.

Comment: *glug* is used when liquid is poured through a narrow opening ***such that air is not allowed to flow in while liquid is flowing out***  creating a partial vacuum inside the container.  When that vacuum gets strong enough, the flow of liquid going out is interrupted lettting air in to equalize the pressures.  When the pressure has equalized, liquid again flows out.  This cycle is what makes the glugging sound.  If the pouring is at an angle where the liquid does not completely fill the  neck of the bottle, air is allowed to continuously replace liquid in the bottle and no glugging occurs.

Answer (score 33):

Gurgle

> Make a hollow bubbling sound like that made
>   by water running out of a bottle.

[Gurgle (Oxford)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gurgle)

Comment: +1 This answer fits my usage as a Native American English speaker.  If I were to write my own definition I would say Gurgle is "the sound produced by the water running into other water, or bouncing off the sides of an open vessel."  Whereas, I would define Glug as "the sound produced when an air bubble enters the mouth of the bottle that is being emptied of a liquid."

Answer (score 4):

Definition from Google. I like this word, it sounds a little less vulgar than glug.

burble
verb
1.
make a continuous murmuring noise.
"the wind burbled at his ear"
synonyms:   gurgle, bubble, murmur, purr, whirr, drone, hum, rumble
"two fountains were burbling outside"

Comment: To burble is what the Jabberwock does as it comes whiffling through the tulgey wood.

Answer (score 4):

Slosh - softer than splash, and also very applicable to drinks.

Comment: Can you cite some examples of this usage from books, articles, etc.?

Comment: @JayElston For usage, you can try 'heard sloshing into glass' or similar in Google Books. Liquid is frequently heard sloshing out of, into and in containers. Sometimes it's just sloshing, without being heard, as it can also be felt or seen doing that.

Comment: I know I could do that. So could anyone else. But citing references gets upvotes -- set [this answer for an example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/449529/is-there-an-idiom-for-your-decision-can-change-at-the-last-moment/449622#449622).

Answer (score 0):

I personally would probably use the word [cascade](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cascade).

> Verb 1. (of water) pour downward rapidly and in large quantities.
>
> **Usage examples::**
>
> - a."water was cascading down the stairs"
> - "rain cascaded from the roof"
>
> **synonyms:** pour, gush, surge, spill, stream, flow, issue, spurt.

Comment: "Cascading" is not a sound, though.